# How can i fix this error : Unreachable code detected in c#

Tags: c#

```
    public bool idletimesetting(string idletime)
    {
        string sUpdateQuery="";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(IUCGlobals.connectionprovider);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbTransaction trans = null;
        try
        {
            sUpdateQuery = "UPDATE IUC_CON_USER SET F_IDLE_MINS =" + Convert.ToInt16(idletime.Trim());
            sUpdateQuery += "WHERE F_USER_ID =" + IUCGlobals.gLoggedUserId;
            trans = con.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Transaction = trans;
            cmd.CommandText = sUpdateQuery;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            trans.Commit();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
            trans.Rollback();
        }
    }
```

In Catch part trans.Rollback(); i'm getting this error, Help me to rectify this,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You `return` before this code, swap the statements.

Comment: FYI typing `c# unreachable code detected` returns the marked duplicate as the first result. Please do your research before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do anything after [`return`](http://The%20return%20statement%20terminates%20execution%20of%20the%20method%20in%20which%20it%20appears%20and%20returns%20control%20to%20the%20calling%20method.), so the `trans.Rollback()` is unreachable:

change this...

```
catch
{
    return false;
    trans.Rollback();
}
```

to this:

```
catch
{
    trans.Rollback();
    return false;
}
```

In [MSDN](http://The%20return%20statement%20terminates%20execution%20of%20the%20method%20in%20which%20it%20appears%20and%20returns%20control%20to%20the%20calling%20method.) words:

> The `return` statement terminates execution of the method in which it
>   appears and returns control to the calling method.